# Get the select list current value not key

Tags: 7

For example, There is a field with 3 options in allowed values, like option1, option2, option3.Is there any function which receive the field name and returns selected values not a keys ?

With this just return key of selected opinion

```
  print ($node->field_opinion['und'][0]['value'])
```

**Update :**

I have create select list field and with this field user can answer and select own value like this

```
1|Stars
2|Nights
3|Awesome
4|Days
```

With above code just return the keys field and i want to return values like "Stars"

Comment: Can you please provide us more information?

Comment: @Jeetendra Kumar UPDATE my friend !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$key = $node->field_opinion['und'][0]['value'];
$label = list_allowed_values(field_info_field('field_opinion'))[$key];
```

Comment: Can i use that for checkbox forms ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `field_info_field()` and `list_allowed_values()` functions to get an array representation of the values you entered in the field's configuration.

The following:

```
$field_opinion_info = field_info_field('field_opinion');
$opinion_values= list_allowed_values($field_opinion_info);
```

should give you access to an array that looks like this stored in `$opinion_values`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Stars
    [2] => Nights
    [3] => Awesome
    [4] => Days
)
```

And from that, you can get the needed value like this:

```
$selected_option = $node->field_opinion[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$selected_value = isset($opinion_values[$selected_option]) ? 
  field_filter_xss($opinion_values[$selected_option]) :
 t('Not a valid option');
```

Note the use of `field_filter_xss()`; according to the documentation of `list_allowed_values()`:

> The strings are not safe for output. Keys and values of the array should be sanitized through field_filter_xss() before being displayed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Stefanos Petrakis but result Must have selected value, your code return all value !

Comment: @BijanZand That is also described in the answer, look for the `$selected_value` variable in my code example. And pay attention to the use of `field_filter_xss` function.